# For Brownian motion $B_s$, $\forall F \in \mathcal F_t \ : E[1_F(B_u-B_t)]=P[F]E[B_u-B_t]$ imply $B_u-B_t $ is independent of $\mathcal F_t $?

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

**I wonder if the claim in the title is correct?** The full context is this: I let $\mathcal F_t ^B:=\sigma(B_s,s \le t )$. I know that for every $u>t \ : B_u-B_t$ is independent of $\mathcal F_t^B $.

We "enlarge" $\mathcal F_t^B $ with all the null sets $\mathcal N $, that is we let $\mathcal F_t :=\sigma(\mathcal F_t^B ,\mathcal N)$ - and I want to show that or every $u>t \ : B_u-B_t$ is independent of $\mathcal F_t$ also holds.

Given $F \in \mathcal F_t $ we have by the definition of completion that $F=\bar F \cup N $ where $\bar F \in \mathcal F_t^B $ and $N \in \mathcal N $. For this we easily se that $E[1_F(B_u-B_t)]=P[F]E[B_u-B_t]$. Which says that $1_F $ and $B_u-B_t $ are **uncorrelated**, does it also imply independence?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you _had_ $E(1_F \varphi(B_u - B_t))=P(F)E(\varphi(B_u-B_t))$ for all $F \in \mathscr{F}_t$ and ALL $\varphi$ continuous with compact support, then the result would be true upon appealing to "standard" approximations.

Comment: In my previous comment, replace "would be true" by "would be provable." In my answer below I showed the conclusion _is_ true.

Comment: May I ask for a sketch of this? I know that this class of functions determine the measure, or the distribution of $B_u-B_t $

Comment: Exactly! So you have, for $F$ fixed, upon approximating measurable and bounded $f$ by continuous functions, $E(1_F f(B_u - B_t)) = P(F) E(f(B_u - B_t)),$ so we would get $E(1_F 1_A(B_u - B_t)) = P(F)P(B_u-B_t \in A)$ and since $F$ _was_ arbitrary, the result would follow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Claim.** If $\mathscr{X}$ and $\mathscr{Y}$ are two sigma fields, and $\bar{\mathscr{X}}$ and $\bar{\mathscr{Y}}$ denote their completions, then the condition $\mathscr{X}$ and $\mathscr{Y}$ are mutually independent is *necessary* and *sufficient* for the mutual independence of $\bar{\mathscr{X}}$ and $\bar{\mathscr{Y}}.$

*Proof.* The *necessity* is obvious, as for the sufficency, consider events $\mathrm{X} \cup \mathrm{M}$ and $\mathrm{Y} \cup \mathrm{N}$ in $\bar{\mathscr{X}}$ and $\bar{\mathscr{Y}},$ respectively. Then, $(\mathrm{X} \cup \mathrm{M}) \cap (\mathrm{Y} \cup \mathrm{N}) \subset (\mathrm{X} \cap \mathrm{Y}) \cup \mathrm{M} \cup \mathrm{N}$ and so $$\mathbf{P}(\mathrm{X} \cap \mathrm{Y}) \leq \mathbf{P}((\mathrm{X} \cup \mathrm{M}) \cap (\mathrm{Y} \cup \mathrm{N})) \leq \mathbf{P}(\mathrm{X} \cap \mathrm{Y}) + \mathbf{P}(\mathrm{M}) + \mathbf{P}(\mathrm{N}),$$
proving the claim.

**Proof of exercise.** Since $\sigma(B_u - B_t)$ and $\mathscr{F}^B_t$ are independent so are their completions and so are $\sigma(B_u - B_t)$ and $\mathscr{F}_t.$ Q.E.D.

Comment: And I know that you asked something different, but it is not clear at all how to pass from the expectation of $X$ to the probabilities of $\{X \in \mathrm{A}\}.$